# Remove automatically added parameters to pagination URLs (custom permalinks)

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination, wordpress-theming, permalinks

Somehow when I changed the permalink of wordpress to a custom permalink the pagination links are not the same as before. Wordpress or the theme are adding query parameters to the url which I don't like. I tried already some of the solutions that I have found on Google, but without any success.

My pagination link is like that: `https://myurl.com/custom-permalink/page/2?q=custom-permalink%2F`

And I need it simply like that: `https://myurl.com/custom-permalink/page/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thankfully I found the solution through this post: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78553

I just needed to change the code a bit and now it works as expected and I get the pagination link like that: `https://myurl.com/custom-permalink/page/2`

Just paste the code into your functions.php and it should work.
Maybe you also have to go to the permalink settings in wordpress and click again on "save changes" after u added the code.

**The code:**

```
add_filter( 'get_pagenum_link', 'wpse_78546_pagenum_link' );

function wpse_78546_pagenum_link( $link )
{
    return preg_replace( '~/(\d+)/?~', '?page=\1', $link );
}
```